# How can I force expression given as function parameter to be calculated after the function call?

Tags: php, testing

I am writing my own testing class. The problem I have encountered is testing whether a function being tested throws expected exception.

I know I can do something like this:

```
try{
  tested_function($expression->beingTestedThatWillThrowAnException());
}catch ($exception){
   if($exception instanceof MyExpectedException){
     echo 'OK';
   } else {
     echo 'FAILED';
   }
}
```

but I'd wish I don't have to write all this `try ... catch` block everytime, so I want to put it in a tester class method.

But when I do something like this

```
class Tester {
   /**
    * @param mixed expression to evaluate
    * @param string expected exception class name
    */
   public function assertException($expression, $expectedException){
     try{
       $expression;
     } catch ($ex) {
       if(is_subclass_of($ex, $expectedException)){
         echo 'OK';
       } else {
         echo 'FAILED';
       }
     }
```

this fails, because `$expression` is evaluated in the moment of method call, so before the program enters `try` block.

The other way I tried is to use `eval` and passing the `$expression` as a string:

```
class Tester {
   /**
    * @param string expression to evaluate
    * @param string expected exception class name
    */
   public function assertException($expression, $expectedException){
     try{
       eval($expression);
     } catch ($ex) {
       if(is_subclass_of($ex, $expectedException)){
         echo 'OK';
       } else {
         echo 'FAILED';
       }
     }
```

This is ok, but it does not allow me to use variables from the main scope, so for example this line fails `$test->assertException('$d->divideBy(0);');` because I don't have the `$d` variable in `Tester::assertException()` scope.

Should I declare *all possible* variable names as global?

How can I force the expression to be evaluated within a method (or in other way achieve the desired result)?

I know that there are ready-to-use unit testers (PHPUnit, SimpleTest etc.) but I was desiring to make this myself.

Comment: If the exception is thrown before entering the method body, you are not testing the method in the 1st place

Comment: @Steve You did not understand. There is a testing method, the one that tests `$expression`. I want to use this method just to check whether the `$expression` throws the exception or not. I'm not testing this method at all

Comment: In your code, some outer method creates this expression. That is where the exception would be raised, and is the method you should test

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this in ordinary PHP. Testing frameworks that want to be able to do this typically use a preprocessor that generates PHP, and the `try/catch` is done there.

Comment: @Steve I've changed a bit the text. Of course, only one method should be tested.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an anonymous function (closure) as $expression, and bind any variables to it using `use` keyword - http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Sorry for poor English, i hope it's understandable.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an direct response to your question, but an other way to achieve the desired result.

PHPUnit has an interesting approach to asserting exceptions by using annotations. I made a small proof of concept to show how that could be done via annotations.

our small framework for unit tests:

```
/**
 * for now, it is added just for Dependency Inversion Principle
 */
interface Test {}

class TestRunner
{
    /**
     * This method will run our tests
     * 
     * @param array $tests
     */
    static public function run(Test $testObject)
    {
        $reflectedClass = new ReflectionClass($testObject);
        foreach ($reflectedClass->getMethods() as $reflectedMethod) {
            // we test only the methods which start with 'test'
            if (strpos($reflectedMethod->getName(), 'test') === 0) {
                $docComment = $reflectedMethod->getDocComment();

                try {
                    // call our method
                    $reflectedMethod->invoke($testObject);
                } catch (Exception $exception) {
                    $expectedExceptions = preg_match_all(
                        '/(\*\s@assertException)(\s+)(?<exception_class>[^\s]*)/',
                        $docComment,
                        $matches
                    );

                    if ($matches) {
                        $status = 'FAILED';
                        if (in_array(get_class($exception), $matches['exception_class'])) {
                            $status = 'OK';
                        }

                        printf("test '%s' status: %s\n", $reflectedMethod->getName(), $status);
                    } else {
                        throw $exception;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and our test:

```
class MyCustomException extends Exception {}

class MyTest implements Test
{
    /**
     * @assertException MyCustomException
     */
    public function testMe()
    {
        // replace this with your expression
        // which should trow the exception
        throw new MyCustomException();
    }
}

TestRunner::run(new MyTest());
```